# Deadlock happens when importing an osgi service using Spring-DM

Tags: osgi, spring-dm

This question is related to a deadlock that happens (at times as described below) when importing an osgi service using spring-dm.

I have recently come across this issue in Spring-DM's ServiceDynamicInterceptor class that leads to a dead lock situation. This happens when two applications contexts are loaded from two bundles. Assume that app ctx A exports an osgi service and app ctx B  imports the osgi service exported from A. The problem happens when both bundles are started together. When app ctx A gets initialized, spring calls the listeners registered for the service synchronously during publishing the osgi service.. Assume that app ctx B gets initialized simultaneously and the osgi import gets executed. First it adds a listener for the osgi service to the bundle context and then goes to lookup the osgi service. Just as the listener gets added to bundle context, app ctx A picks it up and execute the listener. At this point, app ctx B, which acquires a lock, tries to look up the osgi service which is not yet published as the listener is being called which waits for the same lock to be released causing a deadlock. After spring bean creation timeout has reached in 5 minutes (default), app ctx B fails with BeanInitializationException caused by ServiceUnavailableException.

I have listed the code executed in the two threads.Note that both the lookup and the listener are defined in the same file - ServiceDynamicInterceptor.

App Ctx A is waiting for the lock at

```
145: synchronized (lock) {
146:      servicePresent = (wrapper != null && wrapper.isServiceAlive());
147: }
```

App Ctx B is waiting for the osgi service to be published at

```
428: private Object lookupService() {
429:        synchronized (lock) {
430:              return (Object) retryTemplate.execute(retryCallback);
431:        }
432: }
```

This happens at times As I said before, when both bundles are restarted together. However it does not happen every time for obvious reasons. 
My question is whether there is any way that this dead lock could be avoided?

Extracts from thread dump

App Ctx A

```
"SpringOsgiExtenderThread-90" Id=908 in BLOCKED on lock=java.lang.Object@5a9a333f
     owned by pool-45-thread-1 Id=798
    at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceDynamicInterceptor$Listener.serviceChanged(ServiceDynamicInterceptor.java:146)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.invokeServiceListenerCallback(EventDispatcher.java:934)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireEventImmediately(EventDispatcher.java:795)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireServiceEvent(EventDispatcher.java:544)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireServiceEvent(Felix.java:4596)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.registerService(Felix.java:3604)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:346)
    at org.springframework.osgi.service.exporter.support.OsgiServiceFactoryBean.registerService(OsgiServiceFactoryBean.java:310)
    at org.springframework.osgi.service.exporter.support.OsgiServiceFactoryBean.registerService(OsgiServiceFactoryBean.java:279)
    at org.springframework.osgi.service.exporter.support.OsgiServiceFactoryBean$Executor.registerService(OsgiServiceFactoryBean.java:95)
    at org.springframework.osgi.service.exporter.support.internal.controller.ExporterController.registerService(ExporterController.java:40)
    at org.springframework.osgi.service.dependency.internal.DefaultMandatoryDependencyManager.startExporter(DefaultMandatoryDependencyManager.java:320)
    at org.springframework.osgi.service.dependency.internal.DefaultMandatoryDependencyManager.checkIfExporterShouldStart(DefaultMandatoryDependencyManager.java:261)
    at org.springframework.osgi.service.dependency.internal.DefaultMandatoryDependencyManager.discoverDependentImporterFor(DefaultMandatoryDependencyManager.java:254)
      - locked org.springframework.osgi.service.exporter.support.OsgiServiceFactoryBean@2ae6baf0
    at org.springframework.osgi.service.dependency.internal.DefaultMandatoryDependencyManager.addServiceExporter(DefaultMandatoryDependencyManager.java:187)
    at org.springframework.osgi.service.dependency.internal.MandatoryDependencyBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(MandatoryDependencyBeanPostProcessor.java:46)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
      - locked java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap@25dfde15
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:589)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:925)
    at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.access$1600(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:69)
    at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext$4.run(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:355)
      - locked java.lang.Object@c6d4820
    at org.springframework.osgi.util.internal.PrivilegedUtils.executeWithCustomTCCL(PrivilegedUtils.java:85)
    at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.completeRefresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:320)
    at org.springframework.osgi.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor$CompleteRefreshTask.run(DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.java:132)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

App Ctx B

```
"pool-45-thread-1" Id=798 in TIMED_WAITING on lock=java.lang.Object@2b767b9b
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.internal.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:106)
    at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceDynamicInterceptor.lookupService(ServiceDynamicInterceptor.java:430)
    at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceDynamicInterceptor.getTarget(ServiceDynamicInterceptor.java:415)
    at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceDynamicInterceptor.afterPropertiesSet(ServiceDynamicInterceptor.java:472)
    at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.OsgiServiceProxyFactoryBean.createProxy(OsgiServiceProxyFactoryBean.java:215)
    at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.AbstractServiceImporterProxyFactoryBean.getObject(AbstractServiceImporterProxyFactoryBean.java:86)
    at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.OsgiServiceProxyFactoryBean.getObject(OsgiServiceProxyFactoryBean.java:161)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:142)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:102)
      - locked java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap@1a8ffb40
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1442)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:248)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1109)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.ApplicationContextRegistry.lookup(ApplicationContextRegistry.java:43)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.CompositeRegistry.lookup(CompositeRegistry.java:51)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.PropertyPlaceholderDelegateRegistry.lookup(PropertyPlaceholderDelegateRegistry.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.util.CamelContextHelper.lookup(CamelContextHelper.java:119)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteBuilderDefinition.createRouteBuilder(RouteBuilderDefinition.java:64)
    at org.apache.camel.core.xml.AbstractCamelContextFactoryBean.installRoutes(AbstractCamelContextFactoryBean.java:624)
    at org.apache.camel.core.xml.AbstractCamelContextFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractCamelContextFactoryBean.java:276)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(CamelContextFactoryBean.java:235)
    at org.apache.camel.osgi.CamelContextFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(CamelContextFactoryBean.java:64)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
      - locked java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap@1a8ffb40
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.getApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:155)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:86)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:327)
    at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceDynamicInterceptor.publishEvent(ServiceDynamicInterceptor.java:439)
    at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceDynamicInterceptor.access$300(ServiceDynamicInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceDynamicInterceptor$EventSenderRetryTemplate.onMissingTarget(ServiceDynamicInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.internal.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:95)
    at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceDynamicInterceptor.lookupService(ServiceDynamicInterceptor.java:430)
      - locked java.lang.Object@5a9a333f
    at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceDynamicInterceptor.getTarget(ServiceDynamicInterceptor.java:415)
    at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceDynamicInterceptor.afterPropertiesSet(ServiceDynamicInterceptor.java:472)
    at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.OsgiServiceProxyFactoryBean.createProxy(OsgiServiceProxyFactoryBean.java:215)
    at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.AbstractServiceImporterProxyFactoryBean.getObject(AbstractServiceImporterProxyFactoryBean.java:86)
    at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.OsgiServiceProxyFactoryBean.getObject(OsgiServiceProxyFactoryBean.java:161)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:142)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:102)
      - locked java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap@1a8ffb40
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1442)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
      - locked java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap@1a8ffb40
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:925)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:472)
      - locked java.lang.Object@62b8345f
    at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.access$301(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:69)
    at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext$1.run(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:186)
    at org.springframework.osgi.util.internal.PrivilegedUtils.executeWithCustomTCCL(PrivilegedUtils.java:85)
    at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.normalRefresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:182)
    at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext$NoDependenciesWaitRefreshExecutor.refresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:89)
    at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:175)
    at com.xxx.bbb.core.extender.service.bbbManagedServiceFactory$1.run(BbbManagedServiceFactory.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: What do you expect from an answer here? Spring DM is not maintained anymore for years. So the maximum you can achieve is a workaround I think.

Comment: @ChristianSchneider A workaround would be great. Only way I could avoid this is by adding a bean with a delay (say 1s) and calling it from depends-on element in the osgi:reference element in app ctx B. But this will not work if app ctx A take more time to initialize when more beans are added to it.

Comment: Similar issue was raised 5 years back. So it has never been resolved. http://forum.spring.io/forum/attic/spring-dynamic-modules/82295-spring-dm-trying-to-obtain-a-service-hangs

Comment: I got to know later that Declarative Service (DS) would be better option as it does not depend on Spring and has its own component model and component life cycle. These two technologies complement each other.

Comment: DS is a bit limited in its feature set but it is written from the ground for OSGi. So everything involving OSGi services works best in DS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the past I had similar problems with Spring-DM, the workaround that I did, was to track the service with a `ServiceTracker` via the `BundleActivator`. In some cases I also had to customize all the code that was relying on that service (eg: *autowiring*). It was ugly ... but it worked. After some experiments like this, I remember that I also used with success a `FactoryBean` that had the same approach ...